# Basic Query Concerning Discrete Math

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

My professor gave an example located on slide 3 of this [pdf](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/8-2.pdf): can anybody explain to me how he ended up with m_n = 2^(n) - 1. Thanks!

Comment: This question is not software development related. You might try [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step is from

m<sub>n</sub> =2<sup>n−1</sup> +2<sup>n−2</sup> +...+2<sup>2</sup> +2+1.

to

m<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> − 1

There are two ways to make the step. One is to recognize this as a geometric series, and know the rule:

sum=(1-r<sup>n</sup>)/(1-r)

The other is to have played around enough with powers of two to know that if you add up a bunch of them starting from 1, you get the next one, minus one.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

There is a formula for the [sum of the first n terms of a geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

```
1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^{n-1}
= (1 - 2^n) / (1 - 2)
= (1 - 2^n) / (-1)
= 1/(-1) - 2^n/(-1)
= 2^n - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just one of the relations of [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29) that people have figured out over the years:

```
2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 == 2^n - 1
```

You can think of it a lot like the sum of binary numbers:

```
  000001
  000010
  000100
  001000
+ 010000
  ------
  011111 == 1000000 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

```
Mn=2^0+2^1+.........+2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)
```

is the `Nth` term of the sequence `Mk=.....`
And this `Nth` term itself is a sum of a geometrical progression whose 1st term is `1(2^0)` and `common ratio=2`.
And this `sum(Mn)` is

```
  =a[(r^n)-1]/[r-1]
```

where a is 1st term and r common ratio

```
  =1*[(2^n)-1]/[2-1]
Mn=2^n - 1
```